# Cocoa app doesn't show textview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm an iOS developer and I want to create a simple desktop app. I thought the switch would go perfect but it doesn't.

I've created a cocoa app ( from the xCode template ). Now I don't want to use user interface builders and stuff so I wrote my first controller like this:

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTextView *test;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

-(instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        _test = [[NSTextView alloc] init];
        [_test setString:@"DKDDK"];
        [self.view addSubview:_test];

        [_test mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

@interface MainViewController : NSViewController

@end
```

And I just use the NSWindow that is created by the template:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MainViewController * mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];


    [self.window.contentView addSubview:mainView.view];
    mainView.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

When I run the application it gives me:

[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "(null)" nib but no view was set.

I don't know how to solve this. How can I create an app without nib, just like you do on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't loading the view from a NIB then there is little need for a view controller.

Discard the view controller and subclass `NSView` instead, and set that as the window's content view.

Note: you are making a rod for your own back by not using IB.

Comment: Really? On iOS I don't use storyboards or anything and I just subclass UIViewController to set it manually.

Comment: @user1007522 You can use view controllers under OSX, but their main purpose is to facilitate loading from NIB, so you don't need them in your case.

Comment: On your note: when I use NIB then I can't use Masonry (auto layout framework). And I hate doing auto layout in the user interface builder.

Comment: @user1007522 OK, fair enough.